# Pre-commit Docker: .git folder removed after docker-compose build

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit

I'm trying to install pre-commit hooks in my python alpine docker container so I can run them via

```
docker-compose run ... "/py/bin/pre-commit run --all-files"
```

I first install git, then run git init and then install the hooks. It all works fine and I have put in a "ls -a" command for debugging into the building process where the .git folder shows up.

```
.
..
.flake8
.git
.pre-commit-config.yaml
app
core
manage.py
```

However, after the build is finished and I run

```
docker-compose run ... "ls -a"
```

the .git folder has disappeared.

Accordingly, running pre-commit gives me the following error:

```
An error has occurred: FatalError: git failed. Is it installed, and are you in a Git repository directory?
Check the log at /home/django-user/.cache/pre-commit/pre-commit.log
ERROR: 1
```

Below is the full code of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine3.13
LABEL maintainer="dummy-maintainer"

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Add the requirements files temporarily to the container
# to intall the python dependencies.
COPY ./requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
COPY ./requirements-dev.txt /tmp/requirements-dev.txt

# Add the app to the container.
COPY ./app /app

# Add the pre-commit configuration to the container.
COPY ./.pre-commit-config.yaml /app/.pre-commit-config.yaml

# Change the working directory to the app directory
WORKDIR /app

# Use port 8000 for communication
EXPOSE 8000

ARG DEV=false

# 1. Create a virtual environment for the python dependencies.
# 2. Install the postgres client and the build dependencies for the postgres python adapter.
# 3. Create a virtual dependencies folder for the build dependencies. (Makes cleaning up easier)
# 4. Install the python dependencies via pip.
# 5. If this is the development mode, install further python dependencies needed for development.
# 6. Furthermore, create an empty git repository to run pre-commit checks on the source code.
RUN python -m venv /py && \
    /py/bin/pip install --upgrade pip && \
    apk add --update --no-cache postgresql-client && \
    apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp-build-deps \
        build-base postgresql-dev musl-dev gcc libc-dev linux-headers postgresql-dev libffi-dev && \
    /py/bin/pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt && \
    if [ $DEV = "true" ]; \
        then /py/bin/pip install -r /tmp/requirements-dev.txt && \
        apk add --update --no-cache git && \
        git init . && \
        /py/bin/pre-commit install-hooks && \
        ls -a; \
    fi && \
    rm -rf /tmp && \
    apk del .tmp-build-deps && \
    adduser \
        --disabled-password \
        django-user

# Add the py folder to the path to simplify python commands
ENV PATH="/py/bin:$PATH"

USER django-user
```

and this is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - DEV=true
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py wait_for_db &&
             python manage.py migrate &&
             python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_NAME=devdb
      - DB_USER=devuser
      - DB_PASS=changeme
    depends_on:
      - db
  
  db:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    volumes:
      - dev-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=devdb
      - POSTGRES_USER=devuser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=changeme

volumes:
  dev-db-data:
```

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: `he .git folder has disappeare` ? So, why would it be there?

Comment: Because I put it there during the build process to run pre-commit hooks later. I don't want it to disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `volumes:` mount hides everything that's in the image's `/app` directory and replaces it with the host content.  If you ever have a setup where your Dockerfile is reorganizing the file structure with `COPY` commands or `RUN`ning steps to generate files, you can't also use a `volumes:` mount over the same directory.

So in your case, you have a `./.pre-commit-config.yaml` file, and an `./app/manage.py` script.  In the Dockerfile you're merging these two directories so you have both `/app/.pre-commit-config.yaml` and `/app/manage.py`; but then the `volumes:` replace the container's `/app` directory with the host's `./app`, without the pre-commit file.

The advice I'd normally give here is to not try to force everything into Docker space.  On your host system you'll need ordinary development tools like a text editor and a Web browser anyways, and you probably even have Python preinstalled already; install Git too and you'll be able to directly run `git commit` without the `docker-compose run app` wrapper.

If it's really important to you to only have tools in Docker then you need to make the container filesystem layout exactly match the host's.

```bash
FROM python:3.9-alpine
RUN adduser --disabled-password django-user

# Create and switch to a directory to hold the application
WORKDIR /app

# Copy and install the Python-level requirements
COPY requirements*.txt ./
RUN apk add --virtual .build-deps ... \
 && pip install -r requirements.txt \
 && apk del .build-deps

# Copy in the entire source tree
COPY ./ ./

# Explain how to run the container
WORKDIR /app/app
EXPOSE 8000
USER django-user
ENTRYPOINT ["../entrypoint.sh"] # runs wait_for_db, migrate
CMD ["./manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Now since the image has the exact same layout as the host system, you can either bind-mount the entire host source tree or just the `app` subdirectory.

```yaml
volumes: ['.:/app']
```

```yaml
volumes: ['./app:/app/app']
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation of the problem! I'd like to avoid having any dependencies on the system since I collaborate with multiple people on the project. They then only need docker. However, it seems that it would be easier for us to have a pre-commit dependency on the system. This also makes the docker container smaller in size. The final product will also be deployed via docker.